# Can my Macbook Pro run Starcraft Legacy of the Void?

Tags: hardware, games

The days of gaming are long a distant memory. I haven't touched games since 12 years of age. These days, my notebook is used for computational and mathematical modelling.

That said, I do enjoy an occasional gaming session during the holidays.

Here's the spec of my notebook:

MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)
2.7 GHz Intel Core i5
8 GB 1867 MHz DDR3
Intel Iris Graphics 6100 1536 MB

Can it run SC Legacy of the Void?

Answer (score 4):

[Yes.](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/starcraft-ii-system-requirements) Purchase it [here](https://us.battle.net/shop/en/product/starcraft-ii-legacy-of-the-void). Google is your friend, 2pionfour.

Disclosure: no financial stake in Blizzard Entertainment.

Comment: This says it requires a non-integrated graphics card.

However, there's a video on YouTube of a 13" MBP Retina playing it fine. So maybe it will work?

Answer (score 2):

StarCraft 2 works great on the Macbook Pro Mid 2015. I get around 100+fps currently on all low settings on 1280 x 960 resolution. One thing I notice is that the fan gets loud when using OpenGL. Using Metal API although in Beta doesn't even stress out the fan based on my experience.

My specs are:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not.

Your computer specs seems to fit the minimum system requirement for a Mac.

[image: minimum system requiments]

You probably want to turn all your graphics quality to the lowest if you're experiencing lagginess.

### Extra note:

**If you've never installed Starcraft 2 before, you'll likely need to download 7 to 20 GB of game contents. I hope you got unlimited internet download quota and a high speed internet.**

Blizzard and a number of other game companies are moving to making games where the disc is just an installer and the game contents are downloaded from servers.

They don't seem to put the latest game content patches etc on the disc anymore.

Disc 2 of Starcraft 2 Legacy of the Void is completely empty when I put it into my DVD drive, no joke. It's a sad state for the gaming community. Not nice for those on slow, limited internet bandwidth plans.

Happy gaming anyhow :D